# print a list of names in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to print out a list of names and i want to be the one down to another
I'm trying this code:

```
       <tr>
               <td> Names: </td>

           <td>
               <c:forEach items="${names}" var="allnames">                   
                   <c:out value="${allnames} " ></c:out>                           
               </c:forEach>
            </td>

      </tr>
```

But it print the one next to the other. What should i change?

P.S: the result now is: Names:   nick george john
   and i want to be :

```
         Names: nick
                george
                john
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  tag

Names:

```
           <td>
               <c:forEach items="${names}" var="allnames">  
                   <br/>                 
                   <c:out value="${allnames} " ></c:out>                           
               </c:forEach>
            </td>

      </tr>
```

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `<br/>` after each name will print a new line

```
<tr>
           <td> Names: </td>

       <td>
           <c:forEach items="${names}" var="allnames">                   
               <c:out value="${allnames} " ></c:out>                           
               <br/>
           </c:forEach>               
        </td>

  </tr>
```

or you can include the `<td>` tags in your forEach (I'm not quite sure that this will work!)

Answer (score 1):

Add `<br/>` next to `<c:out>`:

```
<c:out value="${allnames} " ></c:out> <br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `<br/>` tag as suggested by @JOHND

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
   <tr> Names: </tr>
   <tr>
      <c:forEach items="${names}" var="allnames">                   
          <c:out value="${allnames} " ></c:out>                           
      </c:forEach>
   </tr>
</td>
```